# Is there a better way to rewrite this ugly switch and if statement combination?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

Essentially I have a system of gamma detectors that are segmented into 4 crystals each, in the case when only 2 of the of crystals register a hit we can determine if the pair was perpendicular or parallel to the plane of the reaction generating the gamma-ray. In the process of writing up the logic for this I wound up writing a huge and ugly combination of switch statements which in each detector checks for the combinations of crystal numbers (which are unique across the whole array of detectors and their crystals).
Here is the code, including the function in question.

```
//The Parallel and Perpendicular designations are used in addition to the Double
//designation for the 90 degree detectors if we get a diagonal scatter in those detectors
//then we use the Double designation
enum ScatterType{Single, Double, Triple, Quadruple, Parallel, Perpendicular};

ScatterType EventBuffer::checkDoubleGamma(int det)
{
    int num1=evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum;
    int num2=evList[crysList[1]].crystalNum;

    switch(det)
    {
    case 10: //first of the 90 degree detectors
        if( (num1==40 && num2==41) || //combo 1
            (num1==41 && num2==40) || //combo 1 reverse
            (num1==42 && num2==43) || //combo 2
            (num1==43 && num2==42)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Parallel; }
        else if( (num1==40 && num2==42) || //combo 1
                 (num1==42 && num2==40) || //combo 1 reverse
                 (num1==41 && num2==43) || //combo 2
                 (num1==43 && num2==41)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Perpendicular; }
        else
        { return Double;}
        break;
    case 11: //second of the 90 degree detectors
        if( (num1==44 && num2==45) || //combo 1
            (num1==45 && num2==44) || //combo 1 reverse
            (num1==46 && num2==47) || //combo 2
            (num1==47 && num2==46)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Parallel; }
        else if( (num1==44 && num2==47) || //combo 1
                 (num1==47 && num2==44) || //combo 1 reverse
                 (num1==45 && num2==46) || //combo 2
                 (num1==46 && num2==45)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Perpendicular; }
        else
        { return Double;}
        break;
    case 13: //third of the 90 degree detectors
        if( (num1==52 && num2==53) || //combo 1
            (num1==53 && num2==52) || //combo 1 reverse
            (num1==54 && num2==55) || //combo 2
            (num1==55 && num2==54)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Parallel; }
        else if( (num1==52 && num2==55) || //combo 1
                 (num1==55 && num2==52) || //combo 1 reverse
                 (num1==53 && num2==54) || //combo 2
                 (num1==54 && num2==53)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Perpendicular; }
        else
        { return Double;}
        break;
    case 14: //fourth of the 90 degree detectors
        if( (num1==56 && num2==57) || //combo 1
            (num1==57 && num2==56) || //combo 1 reverse
            (num1==58 && num2==59) || //combo 2
            (num1==59 && num2==58)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Parallel; }
        else if( (num1==56 && num2==59) || //combo 1
                 (num1==59 && num2==56) || //combo 1 reverse
                 (num1==57 && num2==58) || //combo 2
                 (num1==58 && num2==57)   )//combo 2 reverse
        { return Perpendicular; }
        else
        { return Double;}
        break;
    default:
        throw string("made it to default case in checkDoubleGamma switch statement, something is wrong");
        break;
    }
}
```

I am aware that, because the crystal numbers are global rather than per detector, I could do away with the switch statement and have an enormous set of conditionals linked by or statements, essentially reducing things to 3 control paths, one returning Parallel, one returning Perpendicular, and one returning Double, instead of the 12 control paths with 4 of each that I have. I initially wrote it as it is not thinking and in all honesty, thinking about it, this method reduces the average case number of boolean statements to grind through.

I just worked out how to make it more efficient by switching on the `evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum` I can reduce the evaluations quite a bit, yielding this:

```
ScatterType EventBuffer::checkDoubleGamma()
{
    int crysNum = crysList[1].crystalNum;
    switch(evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum)
    {
    case 40:
        if (crysNum == 41) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 42) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 41:
        if (crysNum == 40) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 43) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 42:
        if (crysNum == 43) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 40) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 43:
        if (crysNum == 42) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 41) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 44:
        if (crysNum == 45) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 47) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 45:
        if (crysNum == 44) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 46) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 46:
        if (crysNum == 47) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 45) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 47:
        if (crysNum == 46) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 44) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 52:
        if (crysNum == 53) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 55) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 53:
        if (crysNum == 52) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 54) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 54:
        if (crysNum == 55) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 53) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 55:
        if (crysNum == 54) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 52) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 56:
        if (crysNum == 57) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 59) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 57:
        if (crysNum == 56) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 58) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 58:
        if (crysNum == 59) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 57) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    case 59:
        if (crysNum == 58) {return Parallel;}
        else if (crysNum == 56) {return Perpendicular;}
        else {return Double;}
        break;
    default:
        throw string("made it to default case in checkDoubleGamma switch statement, something is wrong");
        break;
    }
}
```

The question still remains though, is there any trick to make this shorter? more efficient? more readable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can move nearly everything into a simple table and get away with a single table lookup. I haven't studied your conditions in detail, but it looks like something like this will do the job just fine:

```
// fill the following table in advance using your existing function, or hard-code the 
// values if you know they will never change:
ScatterType hitTable[60][60];


ScatterType EventBuffer::checkDoubleHit(int det)
{
    // read the crystal Nums once:
    unsigned a = evList[cryList[0]].crystalNum;
    unsigned b = evList[cryList[1]].crystalNum;

    switch(det)
    {
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 13: 
    case 14:
      // better safe than sorry:
      assert (a < 60);
      assert (b < 60);
      return hitTable[a][b];
    break;

    default:
        throw string("made it to default case in checkDoubleHit switch statement, something is wrong");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I like this idea, is there anything against making the table smaller and subtracting the offset from the definitions of a and b? Or perhaps making 4 small 4x4 hit tables one for each detector? I ask because otherwise the table covers a LOT of unnecessary / invalid territory and the initialization list I have to write for the table gets enormous. for 60x60 I have to write 3600 values, for 4 4x4 tables I have to write 64.

Comment: Sure. You can optimize a lot on the table size.

Comment: Also note that the tables are symetric, so you could save 50% over your 4x4 tables. You will then index by min(a,b) and max(a,b) instead of a and b directly. Addressing will be a bit more complicated though. Probably not worth the effort but doable.

Comment: Yeah that symmetry is probably not worth exploting 64 elements worth of initialization lists is not bad and with space not an issue it isn't worth the time to swap a and b so they are in value order.

Comment: Looking at the assembly, with my second attempt the worst case was, a calculation of an index for a jump table, 2 absolute jumps, 2 logical compares, 1 mov, and 2 conditional jumps. You knocked it down to calculation of a jump table index, 2 absolute jumps, 4 mov of various types, 1 load effective address, and 1 left shift. It's interesting, I think that conditional jumps can be hard on branch predictors but there seems to be more instructions overall with this method. I will have to benchmark these. That said, your version is more concise and easier to read. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: All that said though, when compiled with -O2 this one once again does better, definitely need to do some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to make it **shorter** is to sort the crystal values before comparing/switching

```
int nummin=evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum;
int nummax=evList[crysList[1]].crystalNum;

if (nummin > nummax) 
{
    tmp = nummin;
    nummin = nummax;
    nummax = tmp;
}
// or like Jarod42 said: std::minmax(numin, numax);

if ((nummin == 40 && nummax == 41) ||  // no need to compare the reverse
    (nummin == 42 && nummax == 43))    // and reduce haft of the comparison
{ ... }
```

Comment: If I look at the assembly for the second shot I took versus, the assembly here, versus my second shot with this, this actually has to execute more "ugly" instructions in all cases, it would certainly help with the first attempt though. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: You may use `std::minmax` (require C++11).

Comment: @JamesMatta optimized compiler's output would be hard to understand, hence "ugly" to human eyes. Nevertheless, "ugly" doesn't mean that it's worse than a cleaner version because there may be more code reorering, inlining, unrolling... making the code larger

Comment: @Luu Vinh Phuc I can read assembly I understood the output when I said ugly I meant that the assembly had more conditional jumps which are expensive.

Comment: conditional jumps **isn't necessarily slower** as long as the branch is predictable (and CPUs are really good at it). In fact using conditional moves may even be slower

Comment: See the explanation from Linus Torvalds why conditional moves (cmov) often suck https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html

Comment: @phuclv While I love the branch predictor, this branch is determining a measured property of a gamma-ray from a nuclear reaction so it is random. Not pseudorandom with a pattern I don't recognize but the predictor might, I mean quantum mechanical process random. Specific gammas might be slightly more likely to be perpendicular or parallel, but this calculation is done for every gamma ray as we analyze time series data from the fusion evaporation reaction. Sadly this branch is unpredictable no matter how good the predictor is so you will get a 50% misprediction rate. Which will never be fast.

Answer (score 0):

A solution combining a 4x4 lookup table and bitwise operations.

Explanation:
This is identical for all four cases, so let's look at the case where `det=10`.

In this case interesting numbers are {40,41,42,43}.
If we look at those numbers in their binary representation, a nice pattern shows up.

The upper number is our mask and is computed by `det*4`.
So in this case our mask is`10*4=40`.

```
 0b101000 (40)  0b101000       0b101000       0b101000
^0b101000 (40) ^0b101001 (41) ^0b101010 (42) ^0b101011 (43)
=0b000000      =0b000001      =0b000010      =0b000011
```

After doing the xor (`^`) between the mask and our allowed numbers, we see that they all have a value in the set {0,1,2,3}. 
So if e.g. `num1 ^ mask < 4`, this means, that only the two rightmost bits  differ from `mask`, or `num1` is at most 3 larger than `mask`. 
If `num1 < mask` at least some bit(s) left of the two rightmost would flip, and `num1 ^ mask` would be at least 4.
So if `num1 ^ mask < 4` is true, `num1` lies in {40,41,42,43}.

Furthermore as this lies in {0,1,2,3}, we can also use it as an index in our lookup table.

Now if the previous calculation is true for both `num1` and `num2`, we have a combined index for the lookup table.

```
int checkDoubleGamma(int det){
    static const int hitTable[4][4] = {
        {Double, Parallel, Perpendicular, Double},
        {Parallel, Double, Double, Perpendicular},
        {Perpendicular, Double, Double, Parallel},
        {Double, Perpendicular, Parallel, Double}
    };

    const int num1 = evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum;
    const int num2 = evList[crysList[1]].crystalNum;

    switch(det) {
    case 10: //0b101000
    case 11: //0b101100
    case 13: //0b110100
    case 14: //0b111000
    {
        const unsigned int mask = 4 * det;
        const unsigned int a = num1 ^ mask;
        if(a < 4){
            const unsigned int b = num2 ^ mask;
            if(b < 4)
                return hitTable[a][b];
        }
        return Double;
    }
    default:
        throw string("made it to default case in checkDoubleGamma switch statement, something is wrong");
        break;
    }
    //Never reaches here
}
```

**Edit: this can be reduced to a 1x4 lookup table**

If we look at at the xor-table for `a^b`, we see that it looks quite similar to our 4x4 lookup table.

```
 ^ 00 01 10 11
00 00 01 10 11
01 01 00 11 10
10 10 11 00 01 
11 11 10 01 00
```

This gives us

```
00,11 = Double
01    = Parallel
10    = Perpendicular
```

So we can reduce the old lookup table to a 1x4 lookup table and use `a^b` as the index.

By looking closer to `a^b`, we see that it's `num1^mask^num2^mask` which is equal to `num1^num2`, which we then will use as the index and save an xor instruction.

This still checks that `num2` is within `{40,41,42,43}`. If `num1` only differs from `mask` in the two rightmost bits, and `num2` only differs from `num1` in the two rightmost bits, then `num2` only differs from `mask` in the two rightmost bits. So leaving out `num2^mask` doesn't change behaviour of the program.

```
int checkDoubleGamma(int det){
    static const int hitTable[4] = {Double, Parallel, Perpendicular, Double};

    const int num1 = evList[crysList[0]].crystalNum;
    const int num2 = evList[crysList[1]].crystalNum;

    switch(det) {
    case 10: //0b101000
    case 11: //0b101100
    case 13: //0b110100
    case 14: //0b111000
    {
        const unsigned int mask = 4 * det;
        const unsigned int a = num1 ^ mask;
        if(a < 4){
            const unsigned int b = num1 ^ num2;
            if(b < 4)
                return hitTable[b];
        }
        return Double;
    }
    default:
        throw string("made it to default case in checkDoubleGamma switch statement, something is wrong");
        break;
    }
    //Never reaches here
}
```